# How to convert xml word table to html using c#

Tags: c#, openxml

I have a word document (.xml file) and I need to convert the tables to html. Is there some kind of existing tool for c#? The way I get the xml is from the document is:

```
Table table = element.Descendants<Table>().First();
string ttt = table.InnerXml;
```

Comment: Usually that's done using [XslCompiledTransform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool**, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of your input and desired output. Also your wording is a little misleading since you are surely not asking for a *tool* but rather for a *method / function* to transform.

Answer (score 0):

The [Open XML PowerTools](https://github.com/EricWhiteDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools) have the functionality to transform Word documents into HTML. Note, though, that they are not using the strongly-typed classes of the Open XML SDK but rather the Linq to XML (e.g., `XElement`) classes.

BTW, you would never use the inner XML to transform an element but rather the outer XML, which includes the `w:tbl` element in your case.